# Are Chinese characters always in a perfect square shape, or are there fonts with rectangular characters?

Tags: characters, writing, fonts

Are all Chinese characters in all fonts placed in a perfect square grid, or are there fonts which make characters slightly rectangular such as 5:6 aspect ratio or 8:9 aspect ratio, etc. E.g. you find stuff like this all over the place, but I haven't seen any rectangle versions.

[image]

Comment: Define the aspect ratio of a Chinese Character in a font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know all fonts put the character in a 'perfect' square.
Handwritten, Chinese/Japanese people do not put them in a perfet square of course.